# How to use joins to fetch unique data from a single table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, join, alias

**I've 4 tables in the database which are:-**

1. branch
2. deposit
3. borrow
4. customers

**Query:** Find loan no, loan city, deposit account number, deposit city of those customers who are living in Nagpur city?

**I've written a query below which successfully fetches three data.**

1. Loan No
2. Loan City
3. Deposit Account number

**But while fetching Deposit city, I'm getting same data as of Loan city.**

Below I'm sharing my code so that you can find where I'm wrong

**My tried code:**

```
SELECT borrow.loanno,
       branch.city AS 'Borrow city',
       deposit.actno,
       branch.city AS 'Deposit city',
       customer.city As 'Customer_city'
FROM   customer
       JOIN borrow
         ON borrow.cname = customer.cname
       JOIN branch
         ON borrow.bname = branch.bname
       JOIN deposit
         ON deposit.cname = customer.cname
            AND customer.city = 'Nagpur';
```

By running the above code, Output I get is

```
loanno  Borrow city Deposit city    actno   Customer_city
  321   Mumbai          Mumbai      104        Nagpur
  375   Mumbai          Mumbai      105        Nagpur
```

Output I want is:-

```
loanno  Borrow city Deposit city    actno   Customer_city
  321   Mumbai          Delhi       104        Nagpur
  375   Mumbai          Banglore    105        Nagpur
```

For more understanding I'm sharing my dB fiddle link so that you get a clear idea.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gaUYxuwuJLsWA4kFeMn9u6/6

Comment: Before I get into this too much, is this even close to a production database?  I have strong opinions on your naming conventions, using strings to join tables vs auto-increment IDs, different string lengths between tables yet that is the constraint?  Are you open for a redesign of what you have into a more normalized context?

Comment: Put what is needed to ask your question in your post, not just at a link. There is no question here. For code questions give a [mre]. And what has your research towards answering this shown? [ask] [Help]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please dont take this the wrong way, but what you have does not appear to be a good database design.  Typically, each table would have an auto-increment integer-based ID key that is unique and carried through to each underlying table.  You have string values for your primary keys.

I know this looks like the beginning of a database design, but you really need some assistance moving forward.

So lets say, you have 5 people named "Anil", what do you do then... your done.  "Anil" is the primary key and you cant change it.  By having an auto-increment, you could have 1000 Anil customers, each with additional information to ensure uniqueness... first name, last name, address, other unique info.

Now on to your branch lookup table.  Same applies.  you have multiple branches in the city of Mumbai. WOULD there ever be a duplicate name?  Possible???  Hence having an ID column auto-increment would resolve, and additional info like customer would ensure uniqueness like the address.  Such as the "Kranti" branch. "IF" you had a Kranti branch on X-street vs Kranti branch on Y-street you would be safe with unique auto-increment numbers.

Now on to deposit and borrow tables.  I know its sample data, but just to show how an oops can happen. Your branch info has a name "Chandani", but your deposit table has "Chandni" (missing the second "a").  I know type-o.

When you have your data entry screens and you find a customer or a branch, the system will have the given "id" of the record to store in your given deposit or borrow table.  Don't do based on strings per the customer example of Anil -- which one if you have 100 Anil customers.  The ID will ensure the correct customer.  Similar with branch.  The ID columns for customer and branch should be used instead (based on a modified database/table structures).

Finally to your query.  You are trying to join the borrow table with the deposit for a given person.  This is just going to give you headaches. There is no guarantee of a deposit for a borrow (or vice-versa).  Now, if you have 5 borrows and 7 deposits for Anil, and you try to query both the way you have it, you will get 35 records being returned (a Cartesian product) because for every record in the borrow table with matching customer will be applied to those deposits.

So, enough for you to consider, sit back, take a breath and digest it.  I can show you a better table structure to handle some context presented here.

As for writing queries, you really need to present it in simple English what you are TRYING to get, then show how you are ATTEMPTING.  Also, there appears to be no match such as a deposit being applied to a given borrow, so what's the point / logic on this.

Again, sincere on what you are up against and would like to help but you may be farther off than you realize.

FEEDBACK

Ok, so it is an assignment -- a bad one, but one none-the-less.  So the issue is you only used one instance of the branch based on the borrower.  What you need is the branch table joined TWICE... once to the borrower, once for the deposit.  In each, I "aliased" it.  When joining to the borrow table I aliased it as "BBranch" for "borrow branch".  For the deposit, I aliased as "DBranch" for "deposit branch".  So each one is joined respectively, so each one will point to its own and pull the city respectively.

```
select 
      borrow.loanno, 
      BBranch.city as 'Borrow city', 
      deposit.actno, 
      DBranch.city as 'Deposit city', 
      customer.city
   from 
      customer 
         join borrow 
            on customer.cname = borrow.cname
            join Branch BBranch
               on borrow.bname = BBranch.bname
         join deposit 
            on customer.cname = deposit.cname
            and customer.city = 'Nagpur'
            join branch DBranch
               on deposit.bname = DBranch.bname
```

Also, indentation to see how / where the tables are joined shows.  You can see it goes

```
customer
  borrow
    branch for borrow
  deposit
    branch for deposit
```

Then you can always see the relationships down stream and not overlapping others / criss-crossing.

The last item is the `and customer.city = 'Nagpur'`.  Don't even know if that was a requirement, but it was in your query.